# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I have created general Link type field and i am trying to browse file from media library but it is giving error!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the media dialog is trying to read the existing values in the field and the value of the field is in the wrong format.

I would try switching on "Raw values" in the Content Editor (Top Ribbon -> View ->> Raw Values). With the raw values on you can see what the contents of the field is. You can then clear the contents of the Link Field. Then try adding a media item again.

Comment: Thanks golden grahams